# What is the reason of unclear downvotes of this topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I get more and more unclear votes down. I posted a question yesterday, and it got downvoted with one. I made several improvements today. And I got another downvote.

This is the question:
*https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53970284/how-can-i-write-an-array-to-a-php-file-with-fwrite*

I understand people have to point out errors of users, but I want to know what is the reason.

Comment: Side note: What I find odd though, is that you stated [*"It returns a string. This question is solved."*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53970284/how-can-i-write-an-array-to-a-php-file-with-fwrite#comment94779311_53970342) and wondering what did in fact solve the question. The answer given or your own? That is unclear.

Comment: In recent years “unclear what you’re asking” has been used to mean “unclear why you need to ask this in the first place”. That’s unfair to questioners but it’s not the fault of the community; the bosses took away our close reason for “you should have been able to answer this yourself with googling, the manual, or finding previous questions asking the same thing”. And when we asked for that reason back, we were told to use “unclear” instead. But net net the reason is the question doesn’t show your own attempts to solve the problem, for a question most people expect is simple to solve or google.

Comment: @DanBron There has never been a close reason for questions that are answerable with basic research.  It's been frequently requested, but never given.  I lament it not existing just as much as you, but it has only ever been a downvote reason, not a close reason.  There have been reasons in the past that people *used* on such questions *even though they didn't apply*, but that doesn't mean there was ever actually a close reason for lack of research.

Comment: @Servy I was referencing “lacks minimal understanding”. People who are so lost they don’t even know they could google the answer (different from people who know but don’t bother trying). PS: on EL&U we do have such a close reason. Today, it’s the most commonly used close reason, and we close ~50% of all Qs asked.

Comment: @DanBron A question that's not poorly researched is not a question that lacks a minimal understanding of the subject.  A question that lacks minimal understanding of the subject is one in which an answer sufficient to get the reader to understand it would be Too Broad.  That doesn't apply to a question that's poorly researched yet still answered with a short and simple answer.  The ELU close reason *is* indeed stating that there's insufficient research.  Again, I'd like to see such a close reason on SO, but there has never been such a close reason, or an equivalent.

Comment: @Servy We are talking past each other; I suspect I understand what you’re saying but you don’t understand what I’m saying, and I further suspect you feel the situation is precisely vice-versa. No matter, this Meta-Q is settled, to the extent MQs ever become settled.

Comment: @DanBron I *understand* what you're saying, it's just not true.  You've stated a given close reason existed on SO, but *it never did*.  You might want it to exist, which is great, by all means, say that; you might think that people use "unclear" as a substitute, you can say that too, but don't say that lack of research used to be a close reason on SO *when it never was*.

Comment: @Servy If you think that’s what I’ve stated, then you do not understand what I’m saying. As I said, we are talking past each other. My prior comment was an indirect invitation to discontinue this thread. It wasn’t effective, so in lieu, this will be my final comment under this question.

Comment: If I'm misunderstanding what you're saying, then what *did* you mean by, "the bosses took away our close reason for 'you should have been able to answer this yourself with googling, the manual, or finding previous questions asking the same thing'" if you don't actually think that there was ever a close reason for insufficient research?  It's a pretty clear statement.

Comment: @Dan Bron. It is difficult to know what is meant with researching or googling in this case. I have searched for a couple of hours. Not knowing what to do makes it hard to ask a question. Both at google as well as here. I think the penalties are exaggerated. I had to use var_export in my question, knowing that makes it easier to search but how could I know?

Comment: Your latest edit read as a deviation from your original question and it added all kind of new question that more or less have answers already here on Meta and otherwise on Meta.SE. For that reason I have rolled-back that edit. After you have done your research you're free to post a new question.

Answer (score 14):

There are several problematic points with the question (besides suboptimal code formatting and capitalization of the title):

- You are not stating the exact error message you get, neither do you tell in which line the error happens.
- Why do you expect the mode param to be related to the problem?
- How can the notice contain "A:\my directory \" (also note the space) when you write to "F:\www..."? Is the notice the error you talk in the beginning? Is it then an error or a notice?

Comment: (Just to say I am the person who answered the question) I'm a bit confused about your last point - *The code contains variables that are not used at all.*  - I have just checked and I can't see what your referring to?  As for the different directories - don't know OP's config, but I run some stuff via CLI and then run my web app via a Docker container, so the paths are different depending on how I run my app.

Comment: @NigelRen: `$var5 = '$data';` and `$var6 = '$fruit';` aren't used anywhere (or are they?). About the paths: If that's the case, then op has to state that. Given that they deal with a file writing issue, a wrong write path could be very relevant.

Comment: The line `$var5  = '" . $data . "';` in PHP, where you have a variable in a string (in this case `$var5`), the language will substitute the value of that variable.  As this is set to `'$data'`(note the single quotes), then  the result would be `$data  = '...`.  The issue of file permissions is misguided and the file is generated, but not with the content OP wanted.

Comment: @NigelRen: You're right. I removed the unused variable part.

Comment: Just 1 last comment (unfortunately I will be away from my computer over New Year) is that although point 1 may be that OP didn't clearly state his problem.  Points 2 and 3 may be good questions to OP and require a comment and need clarification - but do they really say *This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*

Comment: @NigelRen If you have to ask op and it's missing a clear problem statement: yes, the question is unclear and not useful. If I would have encountered it on the main page, I probably would have voted to close as off-topic.

Comment: I removed code that was not needed to get the question. I voted to get it undeleted, can others please vote for that too. It is a good question and it is not really asked before. It is answered maybe. But the point of view and the knowledge of the questioner should determine whether a question should be asked and upvoted. Not if the answer is there.